# List all files modified in last 5 minutes excluding .svn directories

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to list all files modified within the last 5 minutes, excluding `.svn` directories.

I've worked together the following script which does not seem to abide by any `-atime` or `-ctime` params.

```
find . -atime -5m -type d -name .svn -prune -o -type f -print
```

I feel like I'm digging myself into a hole that an extra set of eyes could spot easily.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try a different order of arguments. Your command:

- If an entry is accessed within five minutes **and** is a directory **and** has the name `.svn`, then the entry is ignored
- otherwise, for *all other cases*, if it's a file, print the name

The following command prunes `.svn` directories before descending into them:

```
find . -type d -name .svn -prune -o -mmin -5 -type f -print
```

If a file is a directory **and** has the name `.svn`, ignore it and do not descend into it either. Otherwise, if it is last modified (`-mmin`) within 5 minutes *and* a file, print the filename.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick quite nice. The explanation is paramount in helping me understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`-atime` looks at the last accessed time. I think you're looking for `-mmin`. I've only got cygwin handy so I can't test it...

Answer (score 1):

`-and` is assumed between `-atime` and `-type d`, so you are pruning only SVN directories older than 5 minutes. Try:

```
find . -type d -name .svn -prune -o -type f -mmin 5 -print
```